# OpenShift: External hosts resolving to the same IP

Tags: openshift, openshift-enterprise

Just installed OpenShift and it *mostly* works. I have one slight problem, and that's the fact that DNS resolution for external (non-cluster) hostnames resolve to my OCP router IP address.

For example:

```
oc run --rm -i -t alpine-bash --image=bashell/alpine-bash --restart=Never '/bin/bash'
If you don't see a command prompt, try pressing enter.
bash-4.4#
bash-4.4# ping www.google.com
PING www.google.com (10.222.178.30): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 10.222.178.30: seq=0 ttl=254 time=0.342 ms
64 bytes from 10.222.178.30: seq=1 ttl=254 time=0.161 ms
^C
--- www.google.com ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 0.161/0.251/0.342 ms
bash-4.4# ping 4.2.2.2
PING 4.2.2.2 (4.2.2.2): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 4.2.2.2: seq=0 ttl=56 time=35.461 ms
64 bytes from 4.2.2.2: seq=1 ttl=56 time=39.621 ms
^C
--- 4.2.2.2 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 35.461/37.541/39.621 ms
bash-4.4# ping stackoverflow.com
PING stackoverflow.com (10.222.178.30): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 10.222.178.30: seq=0 ttl=254 time=0.362 ms
64 bytes from 10.222.178.30: seq=1 ttl=254 time=0.200 ms
^C
--- stackoverflow.com ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 0.200/0.281/0.362 ms
bash-4.4# cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 10.222.178.15
search deantest.svc.cluster.local svc.cluster.local cluster.local cloud.wagerworks.com
options ndots:5
```

my DNSMasq config looks like this:

```
[root@ocp-node04 ~]# cat /etc/dnsmasq.d/*
no-resolv
domain-needed
no-negcache
max-cache-ttl=1
enable-dbus
dns-forward-max=10000
cache-size=10000
bind-dynamic
min-port=1024
except-interface=lo
# End of config
server=10.222.160.37
server=10.222.160.38
```

DNS resolution from the hosts themselves work fine. For reference, I am running the ovs-NetworkPolicy plugin. I have two policies applied: default-to-every-namespace and allow-from-same-namespace.

```
- apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
  kind: NetworkPolicy
  metadata:
    name: allow-from-same-namespace
  spec:
    ingress:
    - from:
      - podSelector: {}
    podSelector: null
- apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
  kind: NetworkPolicy
  metadata:
    name: allow-from-default-namespace
  spec:
    ingress:
    - from:
      - namespaceSelector:
          matchLabels:
            name: default
    podSelector: null
```